# create new numpy nd-array by multiple two columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array that includes two columns, one for key and another for num of instances. For example:

```
 key | num_of_instances
 ----------------------
  99  | 2
  88  | 3
  77  | 1
```

I want to flat this to 1-d array in this structure:

```
 [99, 99, 88, 88, 88, 77]
```

i.e. every key in the original 2D-array should appear in the new 1D-array like that the num of instances in the 2nd col in the original array.

Comment: `np.repeat(a[:, 0], a[:, 1].astype(int))`.  You really shouldn't be storing heterogenous dtypes in a single array, use a structured array if you need to.

Comment: it's all number. I'll edit for clarifying,

Comment: Then just use `np.repeat(a[:, 0], a[:, 1])`

Comment: but I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: Then you aren't accurately representing your data.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works for me includes use in **repeat** function.  This function repeats elements of an array and has some configuration options for 1-D, n-D, etc like written [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).

```
data = data.astype(str).astype(int) # this line solved the casting type error I tackled before
one_dimension_data = np.repeat(data[:,0],data[:,1])
```

thanks for  @user3483203 about his informative comments.